# In pubspec.yaml flutter commands (packages upgrades,packages get,flutter upgrades, flutter doctor) option is not available i

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Does it is necessary to click on packages upgrade in pubspec.yaml  file while importing images because option is not available

Comment: Could you rephrase you question to make it clearer? Which option isn't available? Consider updating the question to show your pubspec.

Comment: And, no, it isn't necessary to run `packages get` after editing `pubspec.yaml` to just make changes to assets. (Normally the IDE will want to anyway, but it isn't needed.)